# Jboss Migration. Relation between Jboss 7.2 and Wildfly

Tags: wildfly, jboss-eap-7

I am migrating my application from jboss 6.3 EAP to jboss 7.2 . I see many things related to wildfly which is new to me. My question is what is the relation between jboss 7.2 and wildfly? 
PS: Any help would be appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

JBoss EAP 7 is based on WildFly which is JBoss AS renamed just like Jboss EAP 6 was based on JBoss AS. I'm not sure what you mean by using JBoss EAP without WildFly.